# "Thingy" or "thingie"?

Tags: orthography

I heard "thingy/thingie" very often to refer to "a something". However, I observe it written either way and I don't know what is the correct form.

Dictionary.com redirects *"thingie"* to *"thingy"*, where the article says:

> [**thingy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thingy)
>
> [thing-ee]
>
> noun, plural thingies.
>
> 1. Facetious. any small item whose name is unknown or forgotten.
>
> adjective
>
> 2. of, relating to, or characteristic of inanimate objects.

Then, the Urban Dictionary mentions both: thingy and thingie

> [**thingie**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thingie)
>
> n. a non-specific term for anything
>
> [**thingy**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thingy)
>
> Used to describe an object on the spur of the moment when you have a
>   sudden brain fritz and forget exactly what you were gonna say was.

And [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/thingy) does not find any of them.

What is, then, the proper way to write it?

Comment: thanks for the downvote, could you indicate a reason so I can learn from it?

Comment: Actually, the correct spelling is "thingque" (the "q" is silent).  From Old Norse "tinjie" meaning "dodad".

Comment: @HotLicks But is it "dodad", "doodad", or "doghdad"?

Comment: Thingy or Thingie, It is Scottish, and in some of the example sentences in the OED, few other words are recognizable. "1947   Forfar Dispatch 9 Jan.   Inahent the coonter she's no' near sic a nochtie, shilpit, wee thingie"

Comment: @ab2 I'll go out ona limb and translate that as 'in behind the counter she's not nearly such a naughty, miserable, wee thing.' I guess describing that someone knows how to behave properly when at her work behind a counter.

Comment: @Spagirl  +1  See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368218/what-does-inahent-the-coonter-shes-no-near-sic-a-nochtie-shilpit-wee-thingi  Your limb may be slightly cracked, but not broken.  Nochtie is defined as insignificant, good for nothing, but I suppose it could mean naughty.

Comment: A female thingie, a male thingy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forms are correct; ***thingy*** appears to be the more common form as shown below.

***[-ie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ie&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (suffix):

> - alternative spelling of ***-[y](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-y&allowed_in_frame=0)***; now mostly of -y (3), but formerly of others. (Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thingy%2Cthingie&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthingy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthingie%3B%2Cc0) thingy vs thingie

Comment: With words like thingy, you just do your own thing...ee.

Comment: Thanks! So this seems to be a case in which both are accepted but one gets promoted over time. In this case, specially from the late 80s. I find the "Ngram" *thingy* (:D) a funny way to track these changes, since they get so much credit now that they end up being part of the future canonical knowledge (kind of relativity theory in words?).

Comment: @fedorqui _thingy_ is not a strongly accepted word. Lots of people would object to its use as slang or overly informal. So go with the n-gram and use _thingy_ over _thingie_ as it's way more popular, and furthermore more English words end in -y than -ie.

Comment: In [Google's 'British English' corpus (ngrams)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thingy%2Cthingie&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=en-GB-2012&smoothing=3) it appears that 'thingy' is by far the more common choice nowadays.